# Como ordenar los elementos de un arreglo con php

Tags: javascript, php, array

Estoy adicionando a un arreglo datos utilizando `javascript` que necesito enviar a mi controller para luego procesarlos. Los datos los adiciono de la siguiente forma:

```
      var rechazo = {
                        id_count: 'id_' + count,
                        id_bolsa: $('#id_bolsa option:selected').val(),
                        causa: $('#causa option:selected').val(),
                        es_activo: determinar_es_rechazo(),
                        codigo_barra: $('#codigo_barra').val()
                    };

                    arreglo_rechazada.push(rechazo);
```

Luego los paso para mi controller usando ajax. El punto de mi pregunta radica en que mi controller debo ordenar los arreglos por el codigo de barra (`codigo_barra`) de menor a mayor. El arreglo con ejemplos adicionados queda de la siguiente forma:

```
    Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​

    0: Object { id_count: "id_0", id_bolsa: "20", causa: "---", … }
    ​​
    causa: "---"
    ​​
    codigo_barra: "789"
    ​​
    es_activo: 0
    ​​
    id_bolsa: "20"
    ​​
    id_count: "id_0"
    ​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    ​
    1: Object { id_count: "id_1", id_bolsa: "21", causa: "---", … }
    ​​
    causa: "---"
    ​​
    codigo_barra: "790"
    ​​
    es_activo: 0
    ​​
    id_bolsa: "21"
    ​​
    id_count: "id_1"
    ​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    ​
    2: Object { id_count: "id_2", id_bolsa: "22", causa: "1", … }
    ​​
    causa: "1"
    ​​
    codigo_barra: "---"
    ​​
    es_activo: 1
    ​​
    id_bolsa: "22"
    ​​
    id_count: "id_2"
    ​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    ​
    3: Object { id_count: "id_3", id_bolsa: "23", causa: "---", … }
    ​​
    causa: "---"
    ​​
    codigo_barra: "791"
    ​​
    es_activo: 0
    ​​
    id_bolsa: "23"
    ​​
    id_count: "id_3"
    ​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    ​
    length: 4
```

Notese que en ocasiones el `codigo_barra` puede tener este valor `---` dependiendo si es activ el elemento o no. Mi pregunta es como puedo ordenar el arreglo de menor a mayor teniendo en cuenta que los codigos de barra pueden tener este valor `---`

**Actualización:**

Estoy utilizando este metodo para ordenarlos me me devuelve de resultado true en vez de devolverme un arreglo ordenado.

```
$columns = array_column($input['arreglo_rechazada'], 'codigo_barra');

    $new_array = array_multisort($columns, SORT_ASC, $input['arreglo_rechazada']);
```

Alguna idea???

Comment: a que te referis con obviarlos? Hacer de cuenta que no existen para el algoritmo que ordena? deberias escribir tu propia funcion de ordenamiento. Yo filtraria los objetos con ``codigo_barra === "---"`` y luego ordeno el array de objetos que sí tienen código de barras. Finalmente podrias (o no) concatenarle el array con objetos sin codigo de barras.

Comment: estuve revisando unsort pero no me sirve puesto que no puedo poner una condicional que obvie en el ordenamiento los codigos de barra que tienen ---. Alguna idea?

Comment: no entiendo, vos necesitas que si o si los objertos con ``codigo_barra === "---"`` se queden en la misma posicion en la que se encuentran antes de ordenar? (en este caso se me ocurre que deberias reescribir un algoritmo de ordenamiento) O te serviria que los objetos con codigo de barra se ordenen, y luego, al final (o al principio) del array queden todos los ``codigo_barra === "---"`` juntos? Para esto se me ocurre que podrias resolverlo con funciones del lenguaje

Comment: edite mi pregunta. en el ordenamiento del arreglo pudiera obtener al inicio los codigos de barra iguales a '---' y a continuacion los codigos de barras numericos ordenados de menor a mayor.

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto el problema, había implementado este metodo para ordenar.

```
$columns = array_column($input['arreglo_rechazada'], 'codigo_barra');

        $new_array = array_multisort($columns, SORT_ASC, $input['arreglo_rechazada']);
```

Pensando que `$new_array` seria el arreglo devuelto ya ordenado. Pero no recordaba que `array_multisort` devuelve `true` o `false` en el caso que se realice correctamente el ordenamiento. Luego de percatarme de esto mostre mi arreglo `arreglo_rechazada` y efectivamente mis elementos estaban ordenados; poniendo como primeros elementos a los `codigo_barra === '---'`.